# SwiftUI NavigationLink pops automatically back

Tags: swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I am using the searchable modifier on a List of Titles (Entity) stored in CoreData.
When I click on a link without the search the NavigationLink opens the View (PlayerView) perfectly.
But when I use the search field to search for a specific title and click on the link in the search result the PlayerView opens for just a moment and then pops back to the NavigationView.
Is there anybody out there with a hint how to fix that?
Here is my code:

```
struct NavTest: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Title.restid, ascending: false)])
var coreList: FetchedResults<Title>

@State private var searchText = ""
var query: Binding<String> {
    Binding {
        searchText
    } set: { newValue in
        searchText = newValue
        coreList.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", newValue)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            ForEach(coreList, id: \.self) { (item: Title) in
                NavigationLink(destination: PlayerView(item.title!)){
                    Text(item.title!)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: query)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291367/swiftui-navigationlink-pops-back-when-variable-is-updated) helped me. Try adding this to the NavigationView:

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```