# SwiftUI navigation link screen pops when change color theme

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I have a `TabBar` view with a single tab (for the demo purposes). The tab view screen has a `NavigationLink` button which sends you to a screen with a `Text` box only. The problem that occurs is that whenever I am on the second screen and change the color theme one time - nothing special happens, theme changes and all. When I change it a second time afterwards, the screen just dismisses itself without a reason. Anyone has any idea why this might be happenning?

```swift
struct MyTabView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView(toggle: $toggle)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                }
        }
        .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var toggle: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("madmasdmsadas"), isActive: $toggle) {
            Text("Click")
        }
    }
}

@main
struct AppTesting: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                MyTabView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding binding values to keep it active but the problem doesn't get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the `NavigationView` should be under `TabView`. Not vice versa.

As for why this is happening: I don't have a clear thought about this. Perhaps a bug that causes the `toggle` state to reset. But updating the code accordingly has helped me.

The updated code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyTabView: View {
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
  @State var toggle = false
  
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      NavigationView {
        ContentView(toggle: $toggle)
      }
      .tabItem {
        Text("Profile")
          .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
      }
    }
    .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @Binding var toggle: Bool
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("madmasdmsadas"), isActive: $toggle) {
      Text("Click")
    }
  }
}

@main
struct AppTesting: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MyTabView()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple tabs do I have to put a NavigationView around every single one or is there a way to place one overall for all

Comment: I personally create a new `NavigationView` for each tab instance. Because, you would like to let the user see the tabs when the user is in deeper levels of screens. So, in essence: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `NavigationView` to `NavigationStack` fixed this for me

```
NavigationStack {
    // content and navigation links
}
```

(or if older iOS version)

```
NavigationView {
    // content and navigation links
}.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

related: [SwiftUI: NavigationLink pops back when variable is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291367/swiftui-navigationlink-pops-back-when-variable-is-updated)